# Lost windows Partition Reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 13.10, windows-8

I updated Ubuntu 13.10 and my wireless and ethernet connections stopped working. After trying to get it sorted to no avail I decided to reinstall Ubuntu.

I did have a dual boot with windows 8, but it seems that when trying to reinstall the disk has been reformatted in the early stage of the installation and the windows partition has vanished. I didn't go through with the ubuntu install. But now no OS is being detected on my machine...

Is there any way to get back the windows partition and then reinstall ubunutu where I had the previous installation?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

How did it "vanish"? Plz be specific. Is it unused space? Or is it simply that your GRUB is broken and Win 8 chainloader not accessible? In the latter case, you can get back your chainloader with a Win sysrestore dvd and then reinstall Ubuntu alongside Win.

Comment: Hey Pavel, Using the liveusb when I get to the part where you choose whether to install Ubuntu side by side with windows etc it says that now OS is detected. The hard drive is showing only three partitions, one about 500MB fat32, one about 250 MB ext2 and one partition of 240 GB with a crypt-luks file system. I don't get a grub menu anymore. The windows recovery disk was stored on the hard-drive, but I can't run it as the disk has been repartitioned. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hasn't GRUB rescue mode shown up? You can also create a system restore CD/DVD on ANY other Win7/8 machine and boot from it.